# Reporting score from a different UIViewController IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, game-center

I'm not sure what is going on. 
If i report an int score from the same viewcontroller, it seems to work fine. I can send that number to the leaderboard set up in game center. 
When I report an int score that is from another viewcontroller, it doesn't work. At first I thought it was because the numbers weren't in int64_t. I'm not sure if that is really the issue though.
I'm fairly new to ios programming. If this is a duplicate question, please direct me in the right direction. I really appreciate any help.

```
-(IBAction)report:(id)sender{
    [self reportScore]; //just calling the method
}

-(void)reportScore{
GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];
score.value = HighScore; //HighScore is the int I want from another viewcontroller.

[GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];
```

This line creating the object each time. And thats the reason you are getting the wrong result.

Try to create `GKScore *score` object only once which will be global and then access it.

Comment: Are you suggesting to do this in appdelegate? What do you mean by creating the object each time? Should this not only happen once when I call the method reportScore?

Comment: I mean create that object in one time say in app delegate. When u call the reportscrore function using that object.scrore.value set the value.

Comment: I tried to do what you said, but I don't really know how to do it.
if i move this {GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];
} to app delegate, I get an error saying There's nothing declared "score." Maybe I dont know how to declare global variables.